# Repeatedly dim status bar (SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) on tablets in full screen mode?

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet, statusbar

I know how to dim status bar on Android tablets. I do this with that code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

It works fine but only once. When I touch status bar, it activates and when after that I'm back in my application's activity, status bar is still activated (with icons instead of dots). I tried to log onResume calls, but it's not called, so I googled again and found another solution - using handler for changing visibility of status bar:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    }
});
```

It sometimes works but after several tries it breaks down.

I need this for game - theoretically I can try to call it after every touch or every time in main loop but this seems to be bad idea (and additionally it must be called from specific thread - *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*).

**My question is: what is the best way to implement auto dim of status bar?** Or, in my situation, any way.

Comment: Where do you put `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);`, if you put it in `onCreate`, try to move it to `onResume`, see if it helps

Comment: @Wenhui: As I said, onResume is not called (because onPause is not invoked too - activity is "active" all the time after click on status bar) - to be sure I moved this code to onResume and tested again - it's not helping, so I still don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this is having a View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener on you root view.

When an event fires you have to wait some time to dim them again. A Timer would be suitable.

```
private class MySystemUiVisibilityChangeListener implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);                           
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works for me, all other solutions I have found didn't. Well it worked, but only initially and when touching home button and canceling it. Not when clicking again in game view.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this issue as well (but for the hide navigation flag) and it just seems like google natively disabled the ability to constantly hide/dim the system bar. I do agree with you that constantly calling that method might fail on threads or cause performance issues especially given the fact that so many ontouch events occur on the mobile device.

ultimately, I don't think there's a solution to this unless the user rooted their device to permanently remove the system bar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available back in 2012, but you can now use the activity's `onWindowFocusChanged()` callback:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I altered Karanlos answer a little bit:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    AudioRecordTest.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (ivIndicator.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                ivIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else if (ivIndicator.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                ivIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500);
```

you don't need to make a new class or implement anything. just make a `TimerTask` as in his answer and schedule it using `scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period)`, this method will run the `TimerTask` every `period` of time in milliseconds.